# mootools: how about performance when walking DOM by using css class

Tags: mootools

I'am trying to write a grid Class:
[image]

take first cell for example, It's class attribute will be "cell r1 c1",r1 means first row and c1 means first column, then I use such code to control a whole row:

```
gridContainer.getElements('.r1').addClass('selected');
```

so my question is : **is that good practice to do like this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on the browser and the mootools version.

first thing though, if you want to keep your existing code, use `.getElements("td.r1")` - a more qualified selector will be better for browsers that lack getElementsByClassName and querySelectorAll.

I asked a similar question in my interview with Fabio Miranda Costa of the mootools-core and Slick teams (for v1.3) and you can read his reply here (bottom!): http://fragged.org/intermoos-part-6-fabio-miranda-costa-gets-slick_1213.html

to save you the click, what is the better practice with slick now:

```
// 1
$$("#someid div.something");
// or 2
document.id("someid").getElements("div.something");
```

his reply was:

> **On the first example:**
>
> - If the browser has the querySelectorAll method, the Slick
>     Engine will detect it and use it right
>     away, lightning fast
> - If the browser does not have it, in short–it will do
>     document.getElementById(‘someid’).getElementsByTagName(‘div’)
>     and for each of the found nodes, it
>     will check for the existence of the
>     class ‘something’.
>
> The second example:
>
> - For every browser, it will grab the element with id ‘someid’;
> - Then, if the browser has querySelectorAll, it will use this
>     method to grab all the divs with the
>     ‘something’ class from the ‘someid’
>     context;
> - if the browser don’t have it will use the getElementsByTagName(‘div’)
>     method from the ‘someid’ context and
>     for each of the found nodes it will
>     check for the existence of the class
>     ‘something’.
>
> So, as seen, first one will be faster
>   for most of the browsers and is
>   recommended. From the time of this
>   interview Firefox, Safari, Chrome,
>   Opera and IE >= 8, have the
>   querySelectorAll function.

Comment: we have forced our customers to kill IE6&7, hahaha.